# Web Scrape - How do I click options based on select name using contains value?

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm trying to scrape the below select dropdown menu in order to get the text content.

I cannot use the name as the "_P889O1" changes for each product I will be trying to extract the data from.  However, I was thinking I could use 'contains' but im getting the error that the script is "not a vaild XPath expression"

Depending on the option values the total price changes so I believe a click is required here?

HTML being used:

```
<div class="GC75 ProductChoiceName" id="ProductChoiceName-%%" sf:object="ProductChoiceName" style="color: rgb(36, 36, 36);">
<select name="_P889O1Barrel length" onfocus="if(tf.core.idTextOptionBlur){clearTimeout(tf.core.idTextOptionBlur);tf.core.idTextOptionBlur=null;}if(tf.core.onblurcode){eval(tf.core.onblurcode);tf.core.onblurcode='';tf.core.setFocusID='';}" onclick="cancelBuble(event);if(tf.isInSF())return false;" onchange="tf.core.crFFldImager.replace('P889',this.value.split(core.str_sep1)[7]);var c = this.value;tf.core.crFFldOptPrc.updPrc('P889',this.value?this.value.split(core.str_sep1)[7]:'P889O1',crFFldArr,opt);dBasePrice2('P889',c);return false;" size="1">
<option value="">Barrel length&nbsp;*</option><option value="28&quot;~|`0~|`0.00~|`50220~|`0.000000~|`0.000~|`~|`P889O1C1" origvalue="28&quot;~|`0~|`0.00~|`50220~|`0.000000~|`0.000~|`~|`P889O1C1">28"</option>
<option value="30&quot;~|`0~|`0.00~|`50222~|`0.000000~|`0.000~|`~|`P889O1C2" origvalue="30&quot;~|`0~|`0.00~|`50222~|`0.000000~|`0.000~|`~|`P889O1C2">30"</option>
<option value="32&quot;~|`0~|`0.00~|`50224~|`0.000000~|`0.000~|`~|`P889O1C3" origvalue="32&quot;~|`0~|`0.00~|`50224~|`0.000000~|`0.000~|`~|`P889O1C3">32"</option>
</select></div>
```

Full code snippet:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import shutil
import csv
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame
import re
import os
import urllib.request as urllib2
import locale
import json
from selenium import webdriver
import lxml.html
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select 
os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8"

#selenium requests
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/admin/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("https://www.mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d130_Beretta_Over___Under_Competeition_shotguns.html")
time.sleep(2)

#beautiful soup requests
URL = 'https://www.mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d130_Beretta_Over___Under_Competeition_shotguns.html'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
products = soup.find_all("div", "GC62 Product")


barrels = soup.find_all('select', attrs={'name': re.compile('length')})
[[x['origvalue'][:2] for x in i.find_all('option')[1:]] for i in barrels]


for product in products:
#title
    title = product.find("h3") 
    titleText = title.text if title else ''

#manufacturer name
    manufacturer = product.find("div", "GC5 ProductManufacturer")
    manuText = manufacturer.text if manufacturer else ''

 #image location
    img = product.find("div", "ProductImage")
    imglinks = img.find("a") if img else ''
    imglinkhref = imglinks.get('href')  if imglinks else ''
    imgurl = 'https://www.mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents'+imglinkhref
 
#description
    description = product.find("div", "GC12 ProductDescription")
    descText = description.text if description else ''

#more description
    more = product.find("div", "GC12 ProductDetailedDescription")
    moreText = more.text if more else ''

#price
    spans = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.GC20.ProductPrice span")
    for i in range(0,len(spans),2):
        span = spans[i].text
        i+=1 

        #print(span)
        #print(titleText)
        #print(manuText)
        #print(descText)
        #print(moreText)
        #print(imgurl.replace('..', ''))
        #print("\n")
```

Both times ive included Print(x) just as a visual aid to show myself that its "working"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need `Selenium` as the dropdown menus are generated through Javascript.
2 suggestions: it takes some time for Selenium to dynamically load the page, so implement a `time.sleep` to allow for this. Second, the `xpath` syntax required a small change:

```
import time
browser.get("https://www.mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d130_Beretta_Over___Under_Competeition_shotguns.html")
time.sleep(2)
dropd = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[contains(@name, 'Barrel')]")
```

Output `print(dropd.text)`:

```
Barrel length *
28"
30"
32"
```

Alternatively you can use `BeautifulSoup` in combination with `Selenium`:

```
import time
import re

browser.get("https://www.mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d130_Beretta_Over___Under_Competeition_shotguns.html")
time.sleep(2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)
barrels = soup.find_all('select', attrs={'name': re.compile('length')})
[[x['origvalue'][:2] for x in i.find_all('option')[1:]] for i in barrels]
```

To make it fit your full code:

```
browser.get("https://www.mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d130_Beretta_Over___Under_Competeition_shotguns.html")
time.sleep(2)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)
products = soup.find_all("div", "GC62 Product")

for product in products:
#barrel lengths
  barrels = product.find('select', attrs={'name': re.compile('length')})
  if barrels:
    barrels_list = [x['origvalue'][:2] for x in barrels.find_all('option')[1:]]
    print(barrels_list)
```

Comment: Hi,  Cheers @RJ Adriaansen I wasnt ridiclously far away. How would i go about doing it so that it cycles through listng printing all details for each dropdown type. say for instance  if select[contains(@name, 'barrel')] is present print listing details and barrel length

Comment: I'd use `BeautifulSoup` for this: `barrels = soup.find_all('select', attrs={'name': re.compile('length')})`; and then create a list of all barrel lengths in a for loop or with list comprehension: `[[x['origvalue'][:2] for x in i.find_all('option')[1:]] for i in barrels]`

Comment: Tried the soup.find_all above - throwing a len(barrels) output print 0.  I was thinking a "for i in range(1, len(barrels)):" above my "for product in products:" loop would encapsulate that loop in the range loop?

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't work. I've updated the post. It works when you use this exact code. If you wish to find it per product, you can do `product.find_all('select', attrs={'name': re.compile('length')})` within your `for product in products` for loop, as the barrel lengths are wrapped within the product `div`.

Comment: i'm not sure where im messing this up.  i pasted full code in so you can see exactly what im doing.  the prints are just commented out to avoid too much information

Comment: You have to pass the selenium source code (`browser.page_source`) to Beautifulsoup. I have updated my answer to match your full code.

Comment: That's the money shot! good man RJ - I'm gonna see if I can work with this to use it for other variations of the same.  thanks!  Definitely pushed it in the right direction. Much appreciated.

Comment: when you get a moment would you mind explaining the line barrels_list = [x['origvalue'][:2] for x in barrels.find_all('option')[1:]]  I'll have similar situations to do this and would be best if understood whats going on here.  Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I'm [slicing](https://dev.to/duomly/what-is-slicing-in-python-58f2) two things here. First, `barrels.find_all('option')` returns a list with multiple items, the first is the drop down menu title, `[1:]` omits this first element from the list so only the barrel lengths are left. With `x['origvalue'][:2]` I am slicing the string value of the barrel lengths. It only keeps the first two characters (the numbers), and omits some rubbish code that comes after the numbers.